# How to remove a substrings from a list of strings?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list of strings, all of which have a common property, they all go like this `"pp:actual_string"`. I do not know for sure what the substring `"pp:"` will be, basically `:` acts as a delimiter; everything before `:` shouldn't be included in the result.

I have solved the problem using the brute force approach, but I would like to see a clever method, maybe something like regex.

Note : Some strings might not have this `"pp:string"` format, and could be already a perfect string, i.e. without the delimiter.

This is my current solution:

```py
ll = ["pp17:gaurav","pp17:sauarv","pp17:there","pp17:someone"]
res=[]
for i in ll:
    g=""
    for j in range(len(i)):
        if i[j] == ':':
            index=j+1
    res.append(i[index:len(i)])

print(res)
```

Is there a way that I can do it without creating an extra list ?

Comment: Can we see your current solution? And can you further explain how the current solution is not meeting your needs? Is it performance, correctness, readability, or something else that needs to be improved?

Comment: can you please post the code you have tried? also a longer list of the string. Is this string coming from outside or are you generating it in python? If generating in python, I would recommend using a dictionary

Comment: @mypetlion I have uploaded my solution , thanks for your feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst regex is an incredibly powerful tool with a lot of capabilities, using a "clever method" is not necessarily the best idea you are unfamiliar with its principles.

Your problem is one that can be solved without regex by splitting on the `:` character using the [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split) method,  and just returning the last part by using the `[-1]` index value to represent the last (or only) string that results from the split. This will work even if there isn't a `:`.

```
list_with_prefixes = ["pp:actual_string", "perfect_string", "frog:actual_string"]

cleaned_list = [x.split(':')[-1] for x in list_with_prefixes]
print(cleaned_list)
```

This is a list comprehension that takes each of the strings in turn (`x`), splits the string on the `:` character, this returns a list containing the prefix (if it exists) and the suffix, and builds a new list with only the suffix (i.e. item [-1] in the list that results from the split. In this example, it returns:

```
['actual_string', 'perfect_string', 'actual_string']
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, I was just wondering if there was a better way to do this. Thanks for your solution , helps me a lot.

Comment: Can you refer me to a link where I can read more about this split method ? I can't understand your solution completely, and I would love to read more about it and how to improve

Comment: I've updated the answer with a link to the documentation. It's quite easy to use - just `string.split(what_you_want_to_split_by,  max_number_of_splits)`. [This RealPython tutorial](https://realpython.com/python-string-split-concatenate-join/) might help you as you should learn about `split` and `join` as they're common, powerful string/list manipulation tools.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few options, based upon different assumptions.

### Most explicit

```
if s.startswith('pp:'):
    s = s[len('pp:'):]  # aka 3
```

### If you want to remove anything before the first `:`

```
s = s.split(':', 1)[-1]
```

### Regular expressions:

#### Same as startswith

```
s = re.sub('^pp:', '', s)
```

#### Same as split, but more careful with 'pp:' and slower

```
s = re.match('(?:^pp:)?(.*)', s).group(1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution.